# pandas: aggregate a column to create a non-duplicated sequence

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have the following data frame `my_df`:

```
 name    timestamp     color
 ---------------------------
 John    2017-01-01    blue
 John    2017-01-02    blue
 John    2017-01-03    blue
 John    2017-01-04    yellow
 John    2017-01-05    red
 John    2017-01-06    red
 Ann     2017-01-04    green
 Ann     2017-01-05    orange
 Ann     2017-01-06    orange
 Ann     2017-01-07    red
 Ann     2017-01-08    black
 Dan     2017-01-11    blue
 Dan     2017-01-12    blue
 Dan     2017-01-13    green
 Dan     2017-01-14    yellow
```

I then use the following code to find the color sequence of each person:

```
new_df = my_df.groupby(['name'], as_index=False).color \
    .agg({"color_list": lambda x: list(x)})
```

Then `new_df` looks like:

```
   name        color_list
    -----------------------------------------------
    John        blue, blue, blue, yellow, red, red
    Ann         green, orange, orange,red, black
    Dan         blue, blue, green, yellow
```

However, if I want to create a `color_seq` (no consequtive duplicated colors) instead of `color_list` like below, how do I modify my above code? Thanks!

```
   name        color_seq
    -----------------------------------------------
    John        blue, yellow, red
    Ann         green, orange, red, black
    Dan         blue, green, yellow
```

Comment: lambda x: set(x)?

Comment: no, set couldn't guarantee the sequence order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow non consecutive duplicates,  you must filter carefully.
A way to do that :

```
def filter(l):
    l.append(None)
    return ','.join([x for (i,x) in enumerate (l[:-1])
    if l[i] != l[i+1]])

out=df.groupby('name')['color'].apply(list).apply(filter)
```

for

```
name
Ann     green,orange,red,black
Dan          blue,green,yellow
John           blue,yellow,red
Name: color, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need the output to be in a data frame format, and the result as a new column in the data frame, not just print on the screen. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok.I got it works by using your filter in .agg({"color_list": lambda x: the_filter( list(x))})  Thanks! Could you please explain a bit about what does "x for (i,x) in enumerate (l[:-1])" mean? Thanks!